# Passing an argument as a attribute in a function?

Tags: python, function, pandas

I am trying to write a function that takes in a non-variable to a function. I do not usually write functions but as I learn, I am trying to make my scripts more Pythonic and time saving.

Example:

```
source = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Name': ['John', 'Mike', 'John', 'John'],
        'Year': ['1999', '2000', '2000', '2000'],
        'Message': ['I Love You', 'Will Remember You', 'Love', 'I Love You']
    }
)

def unstack(df, keyword):
    d = (df.keyword.str.split(expand=True).stack)

unstack(source, year)
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
d = (df.year.str.split(expand=True).stack)
```

I know it is quite usual to pass valid keys to the function, but I am trying to get the function to take in the argument and use it as a key.

Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. What is a "non variable"?

Comment: Sorry I might not know the right term. But the example explains it more clearly.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pass the word "year" into the function in order to have the function access the "year" attribute of the object?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Do you want to return something from the unstack function? Otherwise it doesn't do much. Does the line generate an error?

Comment: @khelwood yes, I believe that's what I meant. I apologize for the error. I will be sure to rephrase the question.

Comment: What do you mean by non variable? That makes no sense?

Comment: Fixed my question title. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Pass the string `"year"` and use `df[keyword]`.

Comment: `df.keyword` part of it. keyword cannot be a string

Comment: BTW, including your `import`s would help this be a *complete, verifiable* reproducer. `import pandas as pd` might be standard convention in the pandas world, but that doesn't mean random Python folks know that to be the library you're using. (Shipping a reproducer that *didn't* require a 3rd-party tool such as Pandas would be even better). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `keyword` attribute of `df`, use:

```
getattr(df, keyword)
```

Thus:

```
def unstack(df, keyword):
    d = getattr(df, keyword).str.split(expand=True).stack
```

---

However, it would be better just to make this part of the calling convention:

```
unstack(df.year)    # suggested convention
```

instead of

```
unstack(df, 'year') # practice required by the code above
```

Comment: Thanks. Lesson well learned.